# Google Map Default Array of Markers

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Using a combination of PHP and Javascript, I need to display multiple markers(atleast 50) on a Google map.

I went through the link :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-latlng-literal
On line 15 it says:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    // The below line is equivalent to writing:
    // position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    position: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    map: map
  });
```

I intend doing the following:

```
var markers = [<?php echo $locations ?>];
```

Is it wrong if I do :

```
var markers = [{
    position: {lat: 19.10427, lng: 72.92764},
    map: map
  },
  {
    position: {lat: 19.10432, lng: 72.92751},
    map: map
  }
  ];
```

My intention is then to call showMarkers() in the init function

My js code is :

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"
var map;
var markers = [{
    position: {lat: 19.10427, lng: 72.92764},
    map: map
  },
  {
    position: {lat: 19.10432, lng: 72.92751},
    map: map
  }
  ];
function initialize() {
  var haightAshbury = new google.maps.LatLng(19.10427,72.92764);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: haightAshbury,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  showMarkers();
}
// Add a marker to the map and push to the array.
function addMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}
// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setAllMap(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}
// Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearMarkers() {
  setAllMap(null);
}
// Shows any markers currently in the array.
function showMarkers() {
  setAllMap(map);
}
// Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
function deleteMarkers() {
  clearMarkers();
  markers = [];
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This does not work. In My Firefox console, I can see:
    "TypeError: markers[i].setMap is not a function

Here's the link for jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/P5tXh/4/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The link I referred for all this code is https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

Comment: Your "markers" array is an array of anonymous objects, not google.maps.Markers.  The elements of that array do not have a setMap method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create an array to hold the google.maps.Marker objects equivalent to the markers array
2. create a google.maps.Marker for each entry in the markers array
3. use the array of google.maps.Markers to show/hide the markers

```
// array of google.maps.Marker objects
var gmarkers = [];
function showMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        gmarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker(markers[i]));
    }
    setAllMap(map);
}
```

Then change your existing references to "markers" to "gmarkers"

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P5tXh/5/)

```
var map;
var markers = [{
    position: {
        lat: 19.10427,
        lng: 72.92764
    },
    map: map
}, {
    position: {
        lat: 19.10432,
        lng: 72.92751
    },
    map: map
}];
var gmarkers = [];

function initialize() {
    var haightAshbury = new google.maps.LatLng(19.10427, 72.92764);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: haightAshbury,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
    showMarkers();
}

// Add a marker to the map and push to the array.
function addMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
}

// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setAllMap(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        gmarkers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}

// Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearMarkers() {
    setAllMap(null);
}

// Shows any markers currently in the array.
function showMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        gmarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker(markers[i]));
    }
    setAllMap(map);
}

// Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
function deleteMarkers() {
    clearMarkers();
    markers = [];
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```